# What exactly is the binary inside an ipa file?

Tags: ios, binaryfiles, ipa

I am wondering what exactly is the binary, contained in the .ipa file ( iOS app distribution ) ? And what is its extension ?

On this link https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26550/what-does-ipa-stand-for, I have read

> Each .ipa file is compressed with a binary for the ARM architecture
>   that can only be installed on iOS devices. If you change the extension
>   to .zip you will be able to unzip it and view the contents.

So is this binary the `app_name.app` file ?

Comment: see this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_(file_extension)

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks I had not thought about looking at the wiki page of course..
No really, the meaning of this "binary" file is not explained here

Answer (score 0):

You got it right. The app_name.app file is the binary